# How to show additional fields within the Content Query Web Part

Tags: 2010, content-query-web-part, aggregation

I'm trying to use the Content Query Web Part to display all the tasks within a site collection, I've attached images of the Web Part properties and final output below.

I'm looking for information on how to include additional fields within the output.  Ideally I would like to see the Title, Due Date, Priority, % Complete and provide a link to the actual task form/parent list.

Is anyone able to provide me with an example solution which I can expand on, or information and pointers which will get me started in the right direction?

[image: Query Properties]
[image: Query Properties]
[image: Content Query Output]

Comment: https://williamwmy.wordpress.com/2013/04/17/multiple-columns-on-content-query-web-part and http://edwin.vriethoff.net/2007/09/17/create-a-multi-column-layout-with-the-content-query-tool-web-part/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Content By Query Web Part](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.publishing.webcontrols.contentbyquerywebpart%28v=office.12%29.aspx) is XSL based, by default, `Title`, `Description`, `ImageUrl`, and `LinkUrl` columns (if present) of the items that the query returns are rendered. The Web Part renders the `ImageUrl` column and the `LinkUrl` column as an image and as a hyperlink, respectively.

If you want to query for custom content types and render specific columns from those content types in the Web Part, you must perform some minor customization in the web part.

[CommonViewFields](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.publishing.webcontrols.contentbyquerywebpart.commonviewfields%28v=office.12%29.aspx) property is used to specify the additional fields that you want to display in the Web Part

Please follow article [How to: Display Custom Fields in a SharePoint Content By Query Web Part (ECM)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms497457%28v=office.14%29.aspx) for a more details

---

Article [How to: Customize XSL for the SharePoint Content By Query Web Part (ECM)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb447557%28v=office.14%29.aspx) explains how to customize the rendering

It is also recommended to take a look at article [Customizing the Content Query Web Part and Custom Item Styles](http://www.heathersolomon.com/blog/articles/customitemstyle.aspx),  it gives  a basic understanding how to customize CQWP

Comment: I follow the steps mentioned in the blog to display more column (Title,Body, Category,Published ,Created) on a page from Posts List in Blog Site of O365 online portal but it is not working. Do you have any idea how it can be done for Posts list

Answer (score 3):

You will need to create some custom XSLT which will allow you to present whatever fields you like.  If you need a steer on this there are a couple of blog posts which may help -  http://paylord.wordpress.com/2012/09/28/cqwp-and-xslt-part-1/