# How to add custom property to web part with Content Query Main / Item style file / Exported Web Part SP2013

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-foundation

How do I add a custom property to a content query web part with Exported web part or with Content Query Main / Item Style SP2013?

Comment: [Here you go](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa981241(v=office.14).aspx).

Comment: Can you please elaborate it #Mark?

Comment: You need to find the internal name of your custom property. Then add the property in the exported web part. You can refer to the syntax according to article.

Comment: Also I think this question is duplicated with [this one](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/87042/how-to-show-additional-fields-within-the-content-query-web-part)